# ClassNotFoundException issue in Maven project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I was assigned to complete a project as part of my application for a job. The company send me to install the following requirements:

- OpenJDK 1.8
- Maven 3.x
- Git 2.x
- MySQL 5.x.

I am trying to run the app from the server side (java) and it throws this exception (probably a dependency issue but i can't find it):

> 2020-08-30 07:34:56.850 ERROR
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication:858 - Application run
> failed java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedDataBinder   at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.getExcludeAutoConfigurationsProperty(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:179)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.getExclusions(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:172)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:87)
> at
> org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DefaultDeferredImportSelectorGroup.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:892)
> at
> org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGrouping.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:878)
> at
> org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:804)
> at
> org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:774)
> at
> org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185)
> at
> org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315)
> at
> org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
> at gr.publicsoft.springbootcrud.Application.main(Application.java:12)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
> ... 26 common frames omitted

```
**Pom.xml(general in project)**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
 4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>gr.publicsoft.springbootcrud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-crud</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>springbootcrud-domain</module>
    <module>springbootcrud-service</module>
    <module>springbootcrud-webapp</module>
</modules>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>

**Pom.xml(inside app folder)**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-crud</artifactId>
    <groupId>gr.publicsoft.springbootcrud</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>springbootcrud-webapp</artifactId>



<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>gr.publicsoft.springbootcrud</groupId>
        <artifactId>springbootcrud-service</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eu.bitwalker</groupId>
        <artifactId>UserAgentUtils</artifactId>
        <version>1.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${finalName}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Comment: try to remove the version in your dependency for spring-boot-autoconfigure

Comment: thanks Cyril!Can you please explain why this was happening?

Comment: Spring boot starters make sure all dependencies are compatibles by providing verions for all its dependencies. If you use another version, some classes may not be compatible  or missing.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the `spring-boot-starter-parent` contain `spring-boot-autoconfigure`,see  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.3.3.RELEASE for **Managed Dependencies** .

If you specify this version specifically (that is, there are two different versions), an error may occur.